# SVG in IE9 triggering ActiveX popup on click

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-9, activex

My SVG logo in Internet Explorer 9 causes the "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" on click.

I've tried two different ways to load the image in html.

```
<object data="../logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

and

```
<embed src="../logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
```

Both have the popup come up.  Some other things to note.  I am using this tag to force IE9 into standards mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

The svg image renders fine.  It also works completely fine as a PNG, however, I'd like to know if there is a way to get this to work without just using a PNG.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the PC in question have the outdated and now unsupported Adobe SVG plugin installed? Where is your page running, in the Internet Zone or from your local hard disk? The prompt in question should only appear for pages running on your local PC.

Comment: You are correct in your guessing.  This is an intranet site, and is running from a network drive.  The adobe add-on is not installed.

Is it possible to get that prompt removed for a local page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422050724/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown/) to understand the Local Machine Lockdown that leads to this prompt.

To workaround this, explicitly place your content into the Internet (or Intranet) security zone as described in that article. To wit:

Save your file as UTF-8 or Big Endian Unicode (Little Endian is not supported). Within the first 2kb of the file, just inside the document type declaration, add the following HTML comment:

```
<!doctype html>  
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html><head>...
```

Comment: Very informative article.  It did give me the reason why activex was popping up.  In my case, being an intranet site was triggering the activex.  I was actually testing off a usb drive, which was apparently not in the trusted zone for IE.  Moving it to one of our network drives which was in the trusted zone resolved the issue.  

This apparently did not pertain just to the SVG, even though SVG was involved.  Any script was involved.  Thanks.